# SSL_accept() returns -1 and error set is 1 i.e. SSL_ERROR_SSL

Tags: openssl

I am using method as SSLv23_server_method() and cipher string as "HIGH:MEDIUM:LOW:EXPORT:!SSLv2:!aNULL".
I am not disabling any protocol using SSL_CTX_set_options().

But still the ldap client is not able to connect to server with LOW ciphers
When I fire the below command it fails

> openssl s_client -connect 164.99.163.105:636 -cipher LOW
>       CONNECTED(00000003)
>       5206:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure:s23_clnt.c:596:

```
Error stack: 
    error:1408A0C1:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_hello:no shared cipher
    BIO ctrl called with unknown cmd 7
```

On debugging I see that SSL_accept() call returns -1 and when I check the error with SSL_get_error() it returns the ret value as 1 which is SSL_ERROR_SSL.

What might be the reason of failure?

Comment: `!SSLv2` in the cipher string is not correct. Use a cipher string like `HIGH:!aNULL:!RC4:!MD5`. Then, use context options like `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2` and `SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3`. Also see [SSL/TLS Client](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: Thanks jww for the suggestions.I will give it a try and update.